# highcharts display min / max value of arearange in tooltip only if exist

Tags: php, highcharts, tooltip

I have 2 series of data

average : [timestamp, measure]
range : [timestamp, min,max]

I want to use arearange + line chart as given on the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/arearange-line/).

```
...     
options.tooltip = {
        shared: true,
        //valueSuffix: '<?php echo $sonde_unite;?>'
        //crosshairs: [true, true], 
        formatter: function() {
            var text = '<b>'+ Highcharts.dateFormat('%A %e %B %Y à %H:%M:%S', this.x) +'</b>';
            text += '<br/><b> Zone: <?php echo $sonde_zone;?></b>';
            text += '<br/> <?php echo $sonde_grandeur;?>: '+ this.points[0].y +' <?php echo $sonde_unite;?>';
            console.dir (this);
            text += '<br/> Min: '+ this.points[1].point.low +' <?php echo $sonde_unite;?>';
            text += '<br/> Max: '+ this.points[1].point.high +' <?php echo $sonde_unite;?>';
            return text;
            }
        };
```

This works. However, for some wished cases, min & max are set to NULL, and I don't want to display the min/max value on tooltip. Then I've an error message "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'point' of undefined "

I can't figure out how to avoid display error message and which test I should made

thank you

Comment: Something like `if( typeof this.points[1] != "undefined" ) text += '<br/> Min: '+ this.points[1].point.low +' <?php echo $sonde_unite;?>'; ` ?

Comment: Please recreate your example in fiddle, because supplied has no this issue. So paste your part of data with this bug.